# ошибка "zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, group-by

При построении графика выдает ошибку " zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity "
При этом если идти по пути try-except, то график не строится
Основная часть кода:

```
best = data_ege.groupby("Регион").count().reset_index()

best["Title"] = best["Регион"].astype(str) + ": " + round(best["Объект"], 1).astype(str)

data = gpd.read_file("rus_data.json")
data = data.to_crs({'init':'epsg:3857'})

data = pd.merge(left=data, right=best,
                left_on="NAME_1", right_on="Регион", how="left")
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
area = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)

data.plot(ax=area, legend=True, column="Объект", cmap='Reds') # Ошибка в этой строке!!!

area.legend([], title="\n".join(best.Title), loc="upper left")
plt.title("Количество объектов", fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

Comment: можете привести в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый (чтобы воспроизвести ошибку) пример данных в виде Python кода / текста / CSV? Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался самостоятельно. Проблема была в том, что при объединении столбцов из csv и json, текстовые данные имели одинаковые значения, но при этом с разных регистров. Поэтому, приведя данные из csv к нижнему регистру, а также данные из json к нижнему регистру, график построился.